# How to mask material ui input in formic with using react-input-mask (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mask, formik

Input in formik
Error in type of TextField

```
        <InputMask
          mask="99/99/9999"
          value={formik.values.phone}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        >
          {(inputProps: Props): ReactElement => (
            <TextField
              {...inputProps}
              type="tel"
              label={t("addDriverModal.phone")}
            />
          )}
        </InputMask>
```

Does not work. Props - type declaration from @types/react-input-mask

Answer (score 3):

```js
import { TextField, TextFieldProps } from "@material-ui/core";
import InputMask, {Props} from 'react-input-mask';

    <InputMask
      mask="99/99/9999"
      value={formik.values.phone}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
    >
      {/*
          'props' supplied to TextField weren't matching the required type. 
          Hence we use '&' operator which is for intersecting two types
       */} 
      {(inputProps: Props & TextFieldProps)=>
        <TextField
          {...inputProps}
          type="tel"
          label={t("addDriverModal.phone")}
        />
      }
    </InputMask>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works in TypeScript but you can do this.

```js
/*  Create Your Mask Component Like This */

const phoneMaskComponent = arg => {
 const { inputRef, ...other } = arg;
 const digitRegExp = /[0-9٠-٩۰-۹]/;

 return (
  <MaskedInput
   ref={ref => {
    inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null);
   }}
   guide={false}
   mask={strNumber => {
    return strNumber.split('').map(() => {
     return digitRegExp;
    });
   }}
   pipe={str => {
    const newStr = str
     .replace(/[٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩]/g, d => d.charCodeAt(0) - 1632)
     .replace(/[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]/g, d => d.charCodeAt(0) - 1776)
     .replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');

    return {
     value: newStr,
     indexesOfPipedChars: range(newStr.length * 2),
    };
   }}
   {...other}
  />
 );
};

/* Set The Mask in Your Input Component */
<InputBase
    fullWidth
    isLtr
    name="phone"
    label="Enter Phone Number"
    type="tel"
    value={formik.values.phone}
    /* Use The Mask like This */
    inputComponent={phoneMaskComponent}
  />
```

this mask dose not let user to enter En numbers.

Answer (score 0):

i done that way and it works for me:

```
const MYInput = ({...props}) => (
    <Field
        name={props.name}
        render={({field}) => {
          return (
            <InputMask
              {...field}
              mask={props.mask}
              > 
                {(innerProps) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...innerProps}
                      variant={props.variant ? props.variant : 'filled'}
                      label={props.label ? props.label : ''}
                      />

                )}
              </InputMask>

          )
        }}
      />


);

<MYInput name="Phone" label="Phone" mask="(99) 99999-9999" />
```